# Updating multiple columns using Case

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance

I have a query that looks like below:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET column_x = CASE WHEN x_specific_condition THEN new_value_for_x ELSE column_x END,
    column_y = CASE WHEN y_specific_condition THEN new_value_for_y ELSE column_y END, 
WHERE some_more_conditions
```

Problem with above is, each column (x, y) still gets updated with their own value if some_more_conditions return true irrespective of their specific conditions returning true. I tried removing ELSE from above, but no luck

I am combining as some_more_conditions are same for both cases, I think its better to perform all in 1 update (suggestions welcome)

Do you know if there is a way that can I can perform the above update in 1 query by skipping the individual columns where the specific conditions do not match (basically avoid overwriting of same values)

Comment: If you specify a column should be updated then it will always be updated(Either with new value according to the condition or with original value).

Answer (score 3):

Both columns specified in the SET clause of your UPDATE are going to be touched (written to) for *all* the rows matching the `some_more_conditions`, no matter what `x_specific_condition` or `y_specific_condition` may evaluate to. There is no syntax to work around that while sticking to a single statement.

So, either live with that or go for two statements:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET column_x = new_value_for_x
WHERE some_more_conditions
  AND x_specific_condition;

UPDATE some_table
SET column_y = new_value_for_y
WHERE some_more_conditions
  AND y_specific_condition;
```